# How to convert a D3D9 surface's D3DPOOL type from D3DPOOL_DEFAULT to D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM?

Tags: c++, memory, directx, direct3d9

I have a D3DPOOL_DEFAULT type surface and I want to convert it into a D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM. I know UpdateSurface does the opposite.

Comment: If you have read access to the Default Pool surface, you can lock both surfaces and copy the values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172231(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to DX. But I don't quite understand the pitch in the struct returned by LockRect[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172570(v=vs.85).aspx). Is it the size of the buffer (Heights * pitch)? So I can complete the conversion with memcpy?

Comment: pitch is the byte size of one row. It is sometimes referred to as stride and is used to declare padding at the end of a row. The first row then has address `pBits`, the second `pBits + Pitch` and so on.

Comment: OK, I see. It is just the example in the link that is confusing.